# listview with a custom adapter - every other item element are duplicates

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, custom-adapter

I have come accross a bit of a weird problem (i think) with my listview and its customadapter.

The problem is that I have some different view elements for every item in my listview, such as EditText fields among others.
Whenever I have more than 2 items in the listview, entries to these elements are now in every other item.

Let me give an example:
- I am adding 8 items to the listview.
- I enter a value in the first textfield
- Now the same value repeats in the textfields: 3, 5 and 7
- If I enter a value in the second item's textfield, this value is repeated in textfield of item number: 4, 6 and 8

I hope that you can see the problem now.

Here is some of the relevant code for this problem:

First, the code for my customadapter (CreateProgramAdapter):

```
    public class CreateProgramAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<TrainingPass> trainingPasses;
    private List<TrainingPass> items;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private Context context;

    public CreateProgramAdapter(Context context, List<TrainingPass> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public TrainingPass getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        TrainingPassHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_createprogram_trainingpasses_item, parent, false);
            holder = new TrainingPassHolder();
            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            view = convertView;
            holder = (TrainingPassHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        holder.trainingPass = this.getItem(position);
        holder.trainingPass.trainingPassID = position + 1;
        holder.trainingPassContainer = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.trainingPassContainer);
        holder.trainingPassHeadlineShowHide = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_headline);
        holder.noExercisesYet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_no_exercises_yet);
        holder.exerciseSearchField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_exercise_searchfield);
        holder.trainingPassSetsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.trainingpass_sets_listview);
        holder.exercisesListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.exercises_listview);
        holder.addSetButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_set_button);
        holder.addExerciseButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_exercise_button);
        holder.deleteTrainingpass = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_trainingpass_button);
        holder.doneTrainingpass = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.done_trainingpass_button);

        setupItems(holder);

        return view;
    }


    private void setupItems(TrainingPassHolder trainingPassHolder) {
        final TrainingPassHolder holder = trainingPassHolder;
        int trainingPassID = trainingPassHolder.trainingPass.trainingPassID;

        TextView showHide         = holder.trainingPassHeadlineShowHide;
        Button addSet             = holder.addSetButton;
        Button deleteTrainingPass = holder.deleteTrainingpass;
        final EditText exerciseNameField = holder.exerciseSearchField;

        // Set title of the trainingpass
            showHide.setText("Trainingpass " + trainingPassID);

        // Set name of exercise


        if (trainingPassHolder.trainingPass.tempExerciseName != null) {
            System.out.println(holder.trainingPass.tempExerciseName);
            exerciseNameField.setText(holder.trainingPass.tempExerciseName);
        } else {
            exerciseNameField.setText("");
        }

        // Add 1 default set to exercise
            if (holder.sets.size() == 0) {
                holder.sets.add(1);
            }

        /*
            Set adapter for sets of the listview for the trainingpass
         */

        final TrainingPassSetsAdapter createProgramAdapter = new TrainingPassSetsAdapter(context, holder.sets);
        holder.trainingPassSetsListView.setAdapter(createProgramAdapter);


        exerciseNameField.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                holder.trainingPass.tempExerciseName = exerciseNameField.getText().toString();
                return false;
            }
        });


        /*
            Show / hide the trainingpass
         */
        showHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.trainingPass.visible) {
                    holder.trainingPass.visible = false;
                    holder.trainingPassContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    holder.trainingPass.visible = true;
                    holder.trainingPassContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        /*
            Add set to the listview
         */
        addSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.sets.add(1);
                createProgramAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        /*
            Delete training pass
         */
        deleteTrainingPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                items.remove(holder.trainingPass);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    private static class TrainingPassHolder {
        ArrayList<Integer> sets = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        TrainingPass    trainingPass;
        RelativeLayout  trainingPassContainer;
        TextView        trainingPassHeadlineShowHide;
        TextView        noExercisesYet;
        EditText        exerciseSearchField;
        ListView        trainingPassSetsListView;
        ListView        exercisesListView;
        Button          addSetButton;
        Button          addExerciseButton;
        Button          deleteTrainingpass;
        Button          doneTrainingpass;
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the class TrainingPass:

```
public class TrainingPass {

    public String trainingPassName;
    public ArrayList<Exercise> exercises;
    public int trainingPassID;
    public boolean visible = false;
    public String tempExerciseName;


    public TrainingPass() {
        exercises = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    }

    public void addExercise(Exercise exercise ) {
        exercises.add(exercise);
    }

}
```

An the code for the activity class CreateProgramActivity:

```
public class CreateProgramActivity extends CustomActivity {

    private ArrayList<TrainingPass> trainingPasses;
    private CreateProgramAdapter createProgramAdapter;
    private ListView trainingPassesListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_program);

        trainingPasses = new ArrayList<TrainingPass>();


        trainingPassesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_trainingpasses);
        createProgramAdapter = new CreateProgramAdapter(CreateProgramActivity.this, trainingPasses);
        trainingPassesListView.setAdapter(createProgramAdapter);

    }

    public void addTrainingPass(View v) {
        TrainingPass trainingPass = new TrainingPass();
        trainingPasses.add(trainingPass);

        createProgramAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void addTrainingPassHelp(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Add training pass HELP!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void createProgram(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Create program", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here is the xml layout for the CreateProgramActivity, containing the parent listview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mobileplatformexam.activities.CreateProgramActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutCreateProgram">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add training pass"
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass_help"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass_help"
        android:onClick="addTrainingPass"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\?"
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass_help"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="addTrainingPassHelp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create program"
        android:id="@+id/btn_create_program"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass_help"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass_help"
        android:onClick="createProgram"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView_trainingpasses"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_create_program"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_add_trainingpass" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And lastly, here is my xml layout for the item of the parent listview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Trainingpass"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:height="35dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/trainingpass_showhide_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:height="25dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:src="@mipmap/arrows_up_down"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trainingpass_headline"
        android:id="@+id/trainingPassContainer"
        android:background="@color/blue_bg_neutral"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name of exercise"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_exercise_searchfield"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/sets_container"
            android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_sets_for_exercise"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sets for exercise"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/add_set_button"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/add_set_button" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_no_sets"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_no_sets" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add set"
                android:id="@+id/add_set_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/trainingpass_sets_listview"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add exercise"
                android:id="@+id/add_exercise_button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/add_set_button"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_no_sets"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No sets yet"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_sets_for_exercise"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sets_container"
            android:id="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:background="@color/blue_bg_inputField"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_exercises"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Exercises"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No exercises yet"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_exercises"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/exercises_listview"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_exercises"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_no_exercises_yet" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:id="@+id/delete_trainingpass_button"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:layout_below="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:background="@color/btn_red"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Done"
            android:id="@+id/done_trainingpass_button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/exercises_container"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/delete_trainingpass_button"
            android:background="@color/btn_green"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I really hope that someone can see what the problem is.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code for populating `ArrayList<TrainingPass> trainingPasses;`

Comment: @Paritosh It is there already. TrainingPass trainingPass = new TrainingPass();
        trainingPasses.add(trainingPass); createProgramAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Post your code for TrainingPass class and your activity class. Then we might able to help

Comment: @VishnuPrabhu okay I've added it now. If more is needed, just ask.

Comment: From the above code I understood that you have two listviews, one to display the TrainingPass and to display some integers (holder.sets). I was unable to run your code, since I miss some files notable TrainingPassSetsAdapter and its view. If you could share your code to vishnu.prokarma@gmail.com I will be happy to resolve your issue. :)

Comment: @VishnuPrabhu thanks I'll send it right away :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this behavior is predictable as adapter utilizes views replacing its content with new data. As you didn't set new text value to EditText in the **getView()** method you get EditText with old value, which is that you entered.
So try to add TextWatcher to your EditText and save entered value in the corresponding instance of TrainingPass object. And in the getView() method you have to add of **holder.exerciseSearchField.setText()**. If corresponding TrainingPass object contains previously entered value you have to set it to EditText, otherwise you have to set empty string.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand what mean. I am setting the value of the EditText in the method setupItems(), called by the getView() method. Shouldn't this result in the same behaviour as having the code directly in the getView method?. 
Again the problem is that when I enter a single letter or more in a text field of an odd numbered item, it gives all the other odd numbered items the same value right away.

Comment: Do you speak about holder.exerciseSearchField? I don't see that you set any value for it nor in the getView() netither in the setupItems() method

Comment: Yes the exerciseSearchField. The value for it is set by the user. When the user enters the value in the field for item 1 in the listview, the same value occurs in item number 3, 5 and so on.

Comment: ok, we're speaking about exerciseSearchField.Can you say how many items your list shows at a time? I think two, right?

Comment: well my list shows "x" items, as the items are added on the click of a button with the method addTrainingPass(View v) in the CreateProgramActivity as shown in the question

Comment: I meant not how many items in the list, but how many items from this list shown on the screen.

Comment: I don't know if Im misunderstanding you, but on the click of the button I am adding items to the screen as well. Although the items are kind of repeating themselves, as all odd numbered items are given the same value in exerciseSearchField, when it's changed/entered by the user (the same for even numbered items). So if you look at it like that, then yes there are only 2 items on the screen no matter what. I hope we are not speaking in totally different directions here. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Ok, sow how do you get the value entered to exerciseSearchField? I don't see any code like exerciseSearchField.getText(). Do you save it somehow in the TrainingPass object?

Comment: No I am not saving it (not yet). Anyways, that's not the problem. At least I don't think it is. the problem is that if I have 3 or more items in the listview, every other exerciseSearchField has the same value as soon as some value has been entered.

Comment: Yeah, I got it and I explained why - when you start scrolling adapter gets the first view where you entered some text and fills this view with new value. As long as you don't say adapter to clear this EditText it will contain this value. 
For example, If you would try to enter text in the second item this text will repeat in the item 4, 6 and so forth.

Comment: So as I said you have to add some String field to your TrainingPass object, where you will store entered text and add some logic to your getView() or setupItem() method:  if (null != trainingPass.searchText) { exerciseSearchField.setText(trainingPass.searchText) ; } else { exerciseSearchField.setText(""); }

Comment: I've tried that now, but it's still the same problem. See my updated code in the question. Somehow the views of the odd numbered and the even numbered items must be sharing a reference to the same fields and so. I really can't get this to make any sense. Or can you spot anyhting I've done wrong somewhere. Thanks

Comment: Ok, you've added refilling the edittext with previous entered value, but didn't added Else branch for clearing it: 
if (trainingPassHolder.trainingPass.tempExerciseName != null) { ...  } else { exerciseNameField.setText(""); }

Comment: Of course, I've forgot that. Ok, I've added it to the updated code to the question again. Unfortunately there are still problems. Whenever I enter something in the field, it is set back to empty again. Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: I think this is because you save entered value to holder.trainingPass object, but adapter gets data from trainingPasses list. Remove duplicating object, try to work directly with corresponding TrainingPass from the list. You can get its instance calling getItem() method of your adapter

Comment: That was it! Thank you Oleg! By working directly with the trainingPasses list, I got around the problem :) Well, it was both your guidance and the sample from in bharat's answer that helped me out, but I'll accept your answer as you gave me the direct answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Oleg Osipenko said its because reuse/recycle of listview.. A Sample

```
class Items {
    String name;
    String searchField=""; //to stored edit text values , init with empty string

    //create getter and setter
}
```

Adapter's `getView()`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_adapter_layout, null);
        holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.editText1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);    
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //holder.position to store view position
    holder.position= position;  

    item=items.get(position);

    holder.textView1.setText(item.getName());
    holder.editText1.setText(item.getSearchField());
    holder.editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            //set more conditions if needed - like arg0=null, or empty
            items.get(holder.position).setSearchField(arg0.toString());
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView1;
    EditText editText1;
    int position;
}
```

Get brief explanation about this Visit : **[Creating ListView with EditText and TextWatcher in Android](http://www.webplusandroid.com/creating-listview-with-edittext-and-textwatcher-in-android/)**

Comment: it's definitely the question of reuse/recycle, I said that 4 hours before

Comment: I know.. I just got a sample.

Comment: Thank you @bharat. The sample helped me in the right direction, together with the explanation from Oleg. I accepted his answer and upvoted yours as I can't accept both.